How to load Hugging Face reranker model in 16 bit?
from langchain.retrievers.document_compressors import CrossEncoderReranker
from langchain_community.cross_encoders import HuggingFaceCrossEncoder

model = HuggingFaceCrossEncoder(model_name="BAAI/bge-reranker-base")
compressor = CrossEncoderReranker(model=model, top_n=4)
compression_retriever = ContextualCompressionRetriever(
    base_compressor=compressor, base_retriever=retriever
)

Above is the code I am using for the reranking using HuggingFaceCrossEncoder. But I want to load this model in 16 bit instead of 32 bit. Is there any way I can load this model in 16 or 8 bit
model = HuggingFaceCrossEncoder(model_name="BAAI/bge-reranker-base",use_fp16=True)

I tried using above code but getting below error
ValidationError: 1 validation error for HuggingFaceCrossEncoder

The HuggingFaceCrossEncoder class takes a model_kwargs parameter that is passed to the init of the CrossEncoder class and this class accepts a parameter called automodel_args to pass parameters to the from_pretrained method from huggingface. The parameter you want to pass is called torch_dtype:
import torch
from langchain.retrievers.document_compressors import CrossEncoderReranker
from langchain_community.cross_encoders import HuggingFaceCrossEncoder

model = HuggingFaceCrossEncoder(model_name="BAAI/bge-reranker-base")
print({x.dtype for x in model.client.model.parameters()})
model2 = HuggingFaceCrossEncoder(model_name="BAAI/bge-reranker-base", model_kwargs={'automodel_args':{'torch_dtype':torch.float16}})
print({x.dtype for x in model2.client.model.parameters()})

Output:
{torch.float32}
{torch.float16}

